# Getting bash script to update parent shell's Environment

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am attempting to write a `bash` command line tool that is usable immediately after installation, i.e. in the same shell as its installation script was called. Lets say `install-script.sh` (designed for Ubuntu) looks like:

```
# Get the script's absolute path:
pushd `dirname $0` > /dev/null
SCRIPTPATH=`pwd`
popd > /dev/null

# Add lines to bash.bashrc to export the environment variable:
echo "SCRIPT_HOME=${SCRIPTPATH}" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
echo "export SCRIPT_HOME" >> /etc/bash.bashrc

# Create a new command:
cp ${SCRIPTPATH}/newcomm /usr/bin
chmod a+x /usr/bin/newcomm
```

The idea is that the new command `newcomm` uses the `SCRIPT_HOME` environment variable to reference the main script - which is also in `SCRIPTPATH`:

```
exec "${SCRIPT_HOME}/main-script.sh"
```

Now, the updated `bash.bashrc` hasn't been loaded into the parent shell yet. Worse, I cannot `source` it from within the script - which is running in a child shell. Using `export` to change `SCRIPT_HOME` in the parent shell would at best be duct-taping the issue, but even this is impossible. Also note that the installation script needs to be run using `sudo` so it cannot be called from the parent shell using `source`.

It should be possible since package managers like `apt` do it. Is there a *robust* way to patch up my approach? How is this usually done, and is there a good guide to writing bash installers?

Comment: "*package managers like apt do it.*" - I don't believe this is true. Do you have evidence to support this claim?

Comment: If you remember nothing else about shell programming, remember *a script cannot change its parent's environment*. Which is just another way to express that a *subshell cannot change its parent's environment*. I believe this is a case where "*No, really means ... No*"

Comment: @Rob I did not mean package managers do anything other than achieve my ultimate goal here, to make the command accessible immediately after installation.

Comment: You should not be putting your private scripts in `/usr/bin`. This directory belongs to the OS and should not be modified except by the OS vendor's tooling. The directory `/usr/local/bin` exists precisely to give you a local directory with the same permissions etc as the OS-controlled directory but with the freedom to add and remove stuff as you see fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Neither can `apt`.

A package manager will instead just write required data/variables to a file, which are read either by the program itself, by a patch to the program, or by a wrapper.

Good examples can be found in `/etc/default/*`. These are files with variable definitions, and some even helpfully describe where they're sourced from:

```
$ cat /etc/default/ssh
# Default settings for openssh-server. This file is sourced by /bin/sh from
# /etc/init.d/ssh.

# Options to pass to sshd
SSHD_OPTS=
```

You'll notice that none of the options are set in your current shell after installing a package, since programs get them straight from the files in one way or another.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to modify the current shell is to source a script. That's unavoidable, so start there. Write a script that is `source`d. That script will in turn call your current script.

Your current script will need to communicate with the sourced one to tell it what to change. A common way is to echo variable assignments that can be directly executed by the caller. For instance:

```
printf 'export SCRIPT_HOME=%q\n' "$SCRIPTPATH"
```

Using `printf` with `%q` ensures any special characters will be escaped properly.

Then have the `source`d script `eval` the inner script.

```
eval "$(sudo install-script.sh)"
```

If you want to hide the `source`ing of the top script you could hide it behind an alias or shell function.